# Deploying to Nexus: How to avoid/remove timestamp or incremental naming?

Tags: maven, nexus

I am trying to deploy a project from Jenkins to Nexus but without it creating everytime new versions of my files.

```
project-1.0-20160328.110452-1.war
//..
project-1.0-20160328.110452-2.war
//..
project-1.0-20160328.110452-3.war
```

I tried to use `uniqueVersion`

```
<uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
```

which has no effect.

How can I avoid this and overwrite always the same artifact

```
project-1.0.war
```

Comment: You can simply can't avoid that, cause you are using a `1.0-SNAPSHOT` version. Overwriting always the same artifact like you suggested is against foundation of Maven which is a release which should never being changed or in other words a release is immutable. Maybe you can elaborate more what exactly your problem is and what you like to achieve..

Comment: @khmarbaise In a few words: Save memory. I don't need the old builds and since each deployed `.war` file is ~130MB in size I somehow need older ones to be gone.

Comment: I'm assuming that you are using a repository manager like Nexus where you can configure to remove those SNAPSHOT versions time based or number base...and 130 MiB it not really large..I'm working on builds where every SNAPSHOT build contains around 2 GiB...So just configure the repository manager to remove that based on time limit etc. and you're fine...

Comment: @khmarbaise The thing is that every commit to Jenkins will actually create a new build that gets pushed to Nexus and over time the used memory would become unacceptable for our sysadmins I guess :D But I think I'll follow your suggestion and let Nexus being configured such that it throws away older builds. Thank you for your help!

Comment: About what size are we talking about? How large is the disk storage for your nexus ? How many builds per day do you have?